# Search for subheader text and subset a range of time series data

Tags: r, regex, time-series, subset

I have a large dataset of monthly flow values *for multiple sub-watersheds (A, B, C...)* that were simulated for either 29 or 30 years (all with October 1973 start dates). Multiple land use scenarios (L0, L1, L2...) were simulated for each sub-watershed. The abbreviated large data set (simulation output) looks something like:

```
    L1  L2  L3  L4
Region A    Region A    Region A    Region A    Region A
Oct-73  1158.253987 1277.609802 2075.07222  1175.180347
Nov-73  899.9971049 963.3400574 1236.908427 928.1986959
Dec-73  2014.242414 2843.617772 2476.0352   1900.601679
Region B    Region B    Region B    Region B    Region B
Oct-73  45514.94664 43541.93996 45940.96497 35874.90373
Nov-73  42958.17496 40040.20911 54143.22215 44822.27867
Dec-73  20940.68607 18940.04229 27982.01634 22694.99206
Region C    Region C    Region C    Region C    Region C
Oct-73  36217.37806 39242.19258 55190.01608 41717.96882
Nov-73  30222.61064 39706.71856 31948.43095 29478.23702
Dec-73  25278.32554 29620.78396 25610.99175 24595.77577
```

I have tried numerous approaches in R to parse/subset the data. I would like to subset certain scenarios (columns) in one region at a time (a range of rows). For example, define a new data frame with all months&years for region B, for L1,L2, and L3. This is a massive data set and what I have tried to do is search the data for subheader text strings (i.e. "region B") and subset a set number of rows below the subheader.

```
mydf <- data.frame(my)
linenumber <- as.numeric(row.names(mydf[grepl("Region B", mydf$L1),]))
start <- linenumber+1
end <- linenumber+360
keep.col <- c(L1","L2","L3")
mydf.sub <- mydf[start:end, names(mydf) %in% keep.col]
```

This does not work because each monthly time series is not 360 months (30 yrs) long. Some are 29 years. Any advice on how to search data for a specific text string and subset a range of data below that subheader? I think subheaders embedded within a big matrix of numerical data is the driving issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read in the file skipping line 1.  Then create a logical vector `g` which is TRUE for each header and FALSE for each data row.  `cumsum(g)` is 1 for the header and data rows of the first region, 2 for the second regions, etc.  The names, `nms` is everything before two spaces in the header.  Finally define `reader` which reads a single Region:

```
L <- readLines("myfile.dat")[-1] ##
is.region <- grepl("Region", L)
g <- cumsum(is.region)
nms <- sub("  +.*", "", L[is.region])
reader <- function(x) read.table(text = x, skip = 1)
```

Now we can do things like this:

```
reader(L[nms == "Region A"]) # extract just Region A

reader(L[g == 1]) # same

LDF <- tapply(L, nms[g], reader)  # LDF is a list of all regions
LDF[["Region A"]] # extract just Region A
LDF[[1]] # same
```

LDF looks like this:

```
> LDF
$`Region A`
      V1        V2        V3       V4        V5
1 Oct-73 1158.2540 1277.6098 2075.072 1175.1803
2 Nov-73  899.9971  963.3401 1236.908  928.1987
3 Dec-73 2014.2424 2843.6178 2476.035 1900.6017

$`Region B`
      V1       V2       V3       V4       V5
1 Oct-73 45514.95 43541.94 45940.96 35874.90
2 Nov-73 42958.17 40040.21 54143.22 44822.28
3 Dec-73 20940.69 18940.04 27982.02 22694.99

$`Region C`
      V1       V2       V3       V4       V5
1 Oct-73 36217.38 39242.19 55190.02 41717.97
2 Nov-73 30222.61 39706.72 31948.43 29478.24
3 Dec-73 25278.33 29620.78 25610.99 24595.78
```

For reproducibility here is `L` which can be used in place of the first line marked ## above:

```
L <- c("Region A    Region A    Region A    Region A    Region A", 
"Oct-73  1158.253987 1277.609802 2075.07222  1175.180347", 
"Nov-73  899.9971049 963.3400574 1236.908427 928.1986959", 
"Dec-73  2014.242414 2843.617772 2476.0352   1900.601679", 
"Region B    Region B    Region B    Region B    Region B", 
"Oct-73  45514.94664 43541.93996 45940.96497 35874.90373", 
"Nov-73  42958.17496 40040.20911 54143.22215 44822.27867", 
"Dec-73  20940.68607 18940.04229 27982.01634 22694.99206", 
"Region C    Region C    Region C    Region C    Region C", 
"Oct-73  36217.37806 39242.19258 55190.01608 41717.96882", 
"Nov-73  30222.61064 39706.71856 31948.43095 29478.23702", 
"Dec-73  25278.32554 29620.78396 25610.99175 24595.77577")
```

**UPDATE** Some improvements.

Comment: @mkhaqua: Subsetting can then be facilitated by coercing to something like an `xts` object, e.g. with `LDF <- lapply(LDF, function(x) xts(x[, -1], as.yearmon(as.character(x[, 1]), '%b-%y')))`. You can then subset to a date range by, for example, `LDF[['Region A']]['197310/197311']` (for just Oct and Nov 1973). See `?subset.xts` for more details.

Comment: confused about the line  `reader <- function(x) read.table(text = x, skip = 1)` ? Should I define "x" within `text = x`? When I use "reader" I get: `Error in read.table(text = x, skip = 1) : no lines available in input`

Comment: `reader` is a function which takes one argument which must be a character vector.  It reads those character strings using `read.table` as if they were coming from a file skipping the first string (the header).  There are several examples of using it in the answer.  Type them in exactly as shown.